# Length of a `p`, change `class` in parent `div` jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to adapt the `height` of a parent `div` depending on the text length of its child `p.descr`. I do that by applying a `class`, which in turn has different `height` in CSS. Find below jQuery code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('p.descr').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().length < 90){
          $(this).parent().addClass('bigP90');
        } if($(this).text().length [90,180]) {
          $(this).parent().addClass('bigP180');
        } if($(this).text().length [181,270]) {
          $(this).parent().addClass('bigP270');
        } if($(this).text().length [271,360]) {
          $(this).parent().addClass('bigP360');
        } if($(this).text().length > 360) {
          $(this).parent().addClass('bigP450');
        }
  });
});
```

The problem is that `class` `bigP90` and `bigP450` get applied and work fine, but not the ones in the middle. This means there is something wrong with the syntax but can't figure out what. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `else` keyword? Also, what is `if($(this).text().length [90,180])` supposed to mean.

Comment: I am. It is supposed to mean "if lenght of `p.desc` is between 90 and 180, apply a specific `class`

Comment: Does JS work that way (the [num,num] syntax)?

Comment: @talyaS that's what I have read somewhere, I think in another SO thread, but it doesn't work for me. Can't figure out the right syntax

Comment: Maybe it was a different language, there's nothing like that in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length [90,180]` doesn't test whether the length is between `90` and `180`. Square brackets are for accessing array elements or object properties, so this treats `length` as an array and tries to access the 180'th element of the array.

There's no short syntax for testing a range in Javascript. You simply test if it's above the lower limit and also below the upper limit, e.g.

```
if (val >= 90 && val < 180)
```

But since you've already tested the lower limit with the previous `if`, you can use `else if` to just test the next upper limit, the lower limit test would be redundant.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p.descr').each(function() {
    var len = $(this).text().length;
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    if (len < 90) {
      parent.addClass('bigP90');
    }
    else if (len < 180) {
      parent.addClass('bigP180');
    }
    else if (len < 270) {
      parent.addClass('bigP270');
    }
    else if (len < 360) {
      parent.addClass('bigP360');
    }
    else {
      parent.addClass('bigP450');
    }
  });
});
```